# Display SVG image in WebForms

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, svg, webforms

I want to build a web interface using svg images. To do this, I use web forms. My problem is when I design my interface in VS and add the svg image, either using `<img />` or `<asp:Image />` the image is not shown in design, so I can't see how the svg images are connected in order to create the interface. When I view the aspx page in a browser, the images are shown. I don't want to use PNG or another image format. Is there a way to display the SVG image in aspx page's design tab?

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: This might help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/working-with-svg-files-in-visual-studio-and-visual-web-developer/

Comment: Thanks for replying, VDWWD! Either using `<object />` or `<svg />`, I'm not able to view the image in aspx page' design.

Comment: I wouldn't worry to much as about design view, whats it look like in a web browser?

Comment: @zgood, it's a matter of how to connect the svg images. For example, I have a pump which has connected a pipe. In design view I would be able to connect the images properly from the first try. If I can't see the image in design view, the whole process of building the interface is more chaotic and time consuming. Even if the image tags are connected in design view, in browser the two images are not connected.